# Custom tld function validation in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, validation, jsp, el, tld

I am working in eclipse (Ganymede 3.4.1) and have created a ctl TLD :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd">
 <tlib-version>2.0</tlib-version>
 <short-name>Name</short-name>
 <function>
  <name>readExtendedField</name>
  <function-class>uk.newsint.advertising.wsconnection.ConnectionManager</function-class>
  <function-signature>
    java.lang.String readExtendedField( uk.newsint.advertising.aws.ExtendedFields , java.lang.String )
    </function-signature>
 </function>
</taglib>
```

and referenced it in my jsp (excerpts):

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/appUtils.tld" prefix="au"%>
<c:forEach items="${myAdsForm.result.resultList}" var="lin">
    <tr>
      <td>${au:readExtendedField(lin,"EXTRDATE")}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Eclipse is giving me an EL Sytax error on the this section${au:readExtendedField(lin,"EXTRDATE")} and assigning it to the first quote and the closing bracket {" and )}.

The expression works fine under tomcat but eclipse warns me when I try to commit to the repository and of course shows errors in the problems tab.

Has anyone else suffered this and does anyone have a fix?

Answer (score 0):

You've probably already found your answer by now, but in case you haven't (and to enlighten anybody else that comes across this page, but your custom tags should be treated as tags, not merely elements inside another tag body.  It should be `<au:.../>`

Comment: It should be? I am not sure what you are saying

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot to set up the rest of that as a code sample and it didn't show up

Comment: but this isn't a tag, it's a function.